Create a spreadsheet, or duplicate the active sheet
I am using Google Apps script, which is not bounded to a Google sheet. The target is the following:

If the Google sheet MV_DriveListing does not exist, create it.
If the Google sheet MV_DriveListing exists, duplicate its active sheet.

I tried the following code, without success so far:
function createSS() {
  var ss=DriveApp.getFilesByName('MV_DriveListing');
   if (ss == null){ 
     var newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create('MV_DriveListing');
          SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(newSS);
     var mySS=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
     }
  else {
    var existingSS=SpreadsheetApp.open(ss);
     SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(existingSS);
     var mySS=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
              mySS.duplicateActiveSheet();
  }
}

It gives me the following error:
Exception: The parameters (DriveApp.FileIterator) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.open.
createSS    @ Code.gs:23

Where is the error?

Welcome to stackOverflow! Apparently, you cannot use methods like getActiveSheet, getActiveSpreadsheet, duplicateActiveSheet if you are using standalone scripts. You can only use these methods in bound scripts. You may refer to the Container-bound Scripts article.

When using  standalone scripts you are alway accessing the spreadsheet from the server with no user interface so active script in that case use to deliver Spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].  I did not know that they could not be used at all that way any longer but you can still access sheets by name


  var ss=DriveApp.getFilesByName('MV_DriveListing');
   if (ss == null){ 


The DriveApp.getFilesByName() method gets a FileIterator rather than an array. Use this instead:
    if (ss.hasNext()) { //... do what you want with the file


              mySS.duplicateActiveSheet();


There is no concept of "active sheet" when there is no user at the keyboard running the script. You may want to this pattern instead:
    mySS.getSheets()[0].copyTo(mySS);

To get the first spreadsheet whose name is MV_DriveListing, and duplicate the first tab in that spreadsheet, or create a blank spreadsheet by that name when the file doesn't exist, use something like this:
function createSS() {
  const fileName = 'MV_DriveListing';
  const iterator = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
  let ss;
  let newTab;
  if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(iterator.next());
    newTab = ss.getSheets()[0].copyTo(ss);
  } else {
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(fileName);
  }
  //... do what you want with ss and newTab; newTab will be undefined when ss didn't exist before
}

See DriveApp.getFilesByName() and Sheet.copyTo().

Thank you for the responds! The .hasNext() method works, but the .getSheets()[0].copyTo(mySS) did not. I still could activate the spreadsheet.

As mentioned many times already, the various "activate" methods are user interface methods and not really relevant here. Added sample code in the answer.
